# Replace itext to pdfbox performance

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am evaluating to replace our pdf processing from itext to pdfbox. I did some tests with 200 pdfs with a single page (94KB, 469KB, 937KB) and merged them to one pdf in our application. PDFBox version: 2.0.23.
itext version: 2.1.7. Here are the test results:

[image: test results]

Here is the itext implementation:

```
byte[] l_PDFPage = null;
PdfReader l_PDFReader = null;
PdfCopy l_Copier = null;
Document l_PDFDocument = null;
OutputStream l_Stream = new FileOutputStream(m_File);

// do it for all pages in the editor
for( int i = 0; i < m_Editor.getCountOfElements(); i++ ) {
  l_Page = m_Editor.getPageAt(i);
  l_PDFPage = l_Page.getAsPdf();
  l_PDFReader = new PdfReader(l_PDFPage);
  l_PDFReader.getPageN(1).put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(l_PDFReader.getPageRotation(1) + l_Page.getRotation() % 360));
  l_PDFReader.consolidateNamedDestinations();

  if( i == 0 ) {
    l_PDFDocument = new Document(l_PDFReader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));
    l_Copier = new PdfCopy(l_PDFDocument, l_Stream);
    l_PDFDocument.open();
  }

  l_Copier.addPage(l_Copier.getImportedPage(l_PDFReader, 1));

  if( l_PDFReader.getAcroForm() != null )
    l_Copier.copyAcroForm(l_PDFReader);

  l_Copier.flush();
  l_Copier.freeReader(l_PDFReader);
}

l_PDFDocument.close();
l_Stream.close();
```

Here is the pdfbox implementation:

```
byte[] l_PDFPage = null;
List<PDDocument> pageDocuments = new ArrayList<>();
PDDocument saveDocument = new PDDocument();

try {
  // do it for all pages in the editor
  for( int i = 0; i < m_Editor.getCountOfElements(); i++ ) {
    // our wrapper object for a page
    l_Page = m_Editor.getPageAt(i);
  
    // page as byte[]
    l_PDFPage = l_Page.getAsPdf();
  
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(l_PDFPage);
  
    // save page document to close it later
    pageDocuments.add(document);
  
    PDPage page = document.getPage(0);   
    saveDocument.addPage(saveDocument.importPage(page));
  }

  saveDocument.save(l_Stream);
}
finally {
  // close every page document
  for(PDDocument doc : pageDocuments) {
    doc.close();
  }
  
  saveDocument.close();      
}
```

I have also tried using pdfmerger of pdfbox. The performance was nearly the same as the other pdfbox implementation. But with the 937KB files I run in an outofmemory exception with this implementation:

```
byte[] l_PDFPage = null;
OutputStream l_Stream = new FileOutputStream(m_File);

PDFMergerUtility merger = new PDFMergerUtility();
  
// do it for all pages in the editor
for( int i = 0; i < m_Editor.getCountOfElements(); i++ ) {
  l_Page = m_Editor.getPageAt(i);

  // page as byte[]
  l_PDFPage = l_Page.getAsPdf();
 
  merger.addSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(l_PDFPage));
}

merger.setDestinationStream(l_Stream);
merger.mergeDocuments(null);
```

So my questions:

- Why is the performance (needed time AND memory usage) of pdfbox so bad in comparison to itext?
- Am I missing something in our pdfbox implementation?
- Why I can't close the "page document" after I added the page in "saveDocument"? If i close it there I'd get an error while saving so I have to store the "page documents" and close them at the end.

Comment: try using `addPage` instead of `importPage` (read the javadoc). Also make sure you're using the latest version, 2.0.23. Re close, this is becauuse of shared resources.

Comment: You show the PDFBox code. What is the iText code you compare with? Which versions of those libraries did you use? How much memory did you assign the respective Java process? Etc etc etc... That being asked, PDFBox and iText are architecturally different and, therefore, perform differently well for different tasks.

Comment: I added the itext implementation and the versions of the libs. @mkl I didn't assign custom memory size so I used the default settings of eclipse.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I also tried it just with ```importPage``` which result in more memory usage as with my implementation. It needed the same time for processing.

Comment: itext has a longer history, which seems to result in a bit more compact, cleaned PDF size. The difference in times might point to some issue. Might contact the pdfbox team.

Comment: for PDFBox the way you are merging you will only import the page content and not e.g. AcroForm content. In addition the same resources which might be shared between pages will be imported multiple time. Take a look at PDFMerger (and maybe it's source) to improve that. If you are willing to provide links to PDF samples before/after merge one can take a look

Comment: @MaruanSahyoun I have testet it with PDFMerger but the performance is nearly the same as with the other pdfbox implementation. I have added the source.

Comment: @beep what about the size? I didn't expect it to be faster - in fact it might be a little slower as more content should be merged.

Comment: @beep in addition try using mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting memUsageSetting) and play with the settings. e.g. using temp files will reduce memory usage at the cost of performance.

Comment: It would be interesting to run the profiler to find out where the time is spent. Please share the 469 KB file. Also make sure you use the latest java version. (jdk8 is at 292)

Comment: One detail concerning `saveDocument.addPage(saveDocument.importPage(page));` -  `importPage` itself already adds the page, your also adding it explicitly thereafter might result in an incorrect result document (a detail Adobe Reader won't warn about).

Answer (score 1):

PDFBox and iText are architecturally different and, therefore, perform differently well for different tasks.

In particular iText attempts to write out new contents early, in your case much of the page is written to the output already during

```
l_Copier.addPage(l_Copier.getImportedPage(l_PDFReader, 1));
```

and

```
l_PDFDocument.close();
```

eventually only finalizes the PDF and writes last remaining objects and the file trailer.

PDFBox on the other hand saves everything in the end at once:

```
saveDocument.save(l_Stream);
```

The approach of iText has the advantage of a smaller memory footprint (as you observed) and the disadvantage that you cannot change data of a page once it is written.

(As an aside: the iText architecture has changed from iText 5 to iText 7, in iText 7 you have the choice and can keep everything in memory, but the price here also is a big memory footprint.)

Thus,

> Why is the performance (needed time AND memory usage) of pdfbox so bad in comparison to itext?

The difference in memory use can partially be explained by the above. Also in iText after

```
l_Copier.freeReader(l_PDFReader);
```

the `PdfReader` can be closed (which you leave to the garbage collection to do for you) to free its resources while in your PDFBox code you keep all the source documents open, holding the resources up to the end. (Actually I would have assumed that when you're using `importPage`, you needn't keep them.)

Concerning the time I'm not sure now. You should do some finer clocking and determine where exactly the extra time is used in PDFBox; thus, I second @Tilman's request for profiling data. I assume it's during the final save but that's only a hunch. Also such time differences might depend on structural details of the PDF in question and may be less extreme for other documents.